# Jquery insert hidden field from dropdown is throwing error when trying to submit to access db via asp

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have an asp form that will be completing two actions. The first is to submit the data to the database, the second is to email the data to the person selected in the form.

I have a drop down menu that shows employee names and passes a value of the employee email address.

I'm currently using this Jquery code to pass the employee name to a hidden field and want to use that hidden field to submit to the database.

```
$(document).ready( function (){ 

$("#to").change( function(){

  var selectedValue = $("#to option:selected").val();

  var selectedText = $("#to option:selected").text();

       $("#hiddenText").val( selectedText );

       alert("Hidden field text is: " + $("#hiddenText").val());


 });

 });
```

This appears to work, the alert show the correct value. When I try to submit the form and insert to the database, I get this error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e57' 
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid string or buffer length 
/intranet/EmployeeInfo/Heroes1/heroesPost.asp, line 30

Below is the insert code:

```
    <%
If (CStr(Request("MM_insert")) = "heroes") Then
  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
' execute the insert
Dim MM_editCmd

Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_PhoneDir_STRING
MM_editCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO REACH ([To], Dept, prideSelect, flagpoleSelect, [comment], [from]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
MM_editCmd.Prepared = true
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 203, 1, 1073741823, Request.Form("hiddenText")) ' adLongVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 202, 1, 50, Request.Form("dept")) ' adVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param3", 202, 1, 50, Request.Form("prideSelect")) ' adVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param4", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("flagpoleSelect")) ' adVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param5", 203, 1, 1073741823, Request.Form("comment")) ' adLongVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param6", 202, 1, 100, Request.Form("from")) ' adVarWChar
MM_editCmd.Execute
MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

' append the query string to the redirect URL
Dim MM_editRedirectUrl
MM_editRedirectUrl = "HeroesThanks.asp"
If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
  If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
    MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
  Else
    MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
  End If
End If
Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
  End If
 End If
%>
```

If I "ignore" the hidden field and just submit the value from the drop down, the form submits without error and the information is added to the database.

Any ideas on what I need to change to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Could you tell me which line is line 30? I presume you had includes above the code you have posted?

Comment: MM_editCmd.Execute is the line.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the data you are trying to insert is being truncated, if the string 250 long and your database field only accepts 50 chars then you will get this error.

More info ... check out [Why do I get 80040E57 / 80040E07 errors?](http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/why-do-i-get-80040e57/80040e07-errors.html)

Comment: The database field is set to "memo" which allows for more than 255 characters.

Comment: @user1623347 you should change the type of the `to` field . Why should it be a memo field ?

Comment: I changed it because I thought I was getting the error message because the string was too long. It's the employees full name: last,middle,first. I changed the the type of the to field back to text and set the lenght to 255. I'm still getting the same error.